# const case in vscode snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

Hey i'm looking for a way to make a vscode snippet turn my variable name to const case:

for example

```
${1:regular}
${1:/constCase/}
```

if I write heyThisIsVariable in it, it will become:

```
heyThisIsVariable
HEY_THIS_IS_VARIABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your snippet:

```
"body": [
  "$1",
  "${1/([a-z]+)|([A-Z][^A-Z]*)/${1:/upcase}${2:+_}${2:/upcase}/g}",
]
```

It works for any number (1 to infinity) of "words".

Comment: i cant publicly change your score. so FYI I did upvote you.
But there is a problem , you regex does not support cases where only one word appears.


for example: thisIsTest
would become THIS_IS_TEST,
but the word : test,
would become test 
instead of TEST

Comment: I made a couple of changes so it now works for any number of "words" in the variable name.  [You were unable to upvote before, you need a minimum of 15 reputation.]